# Read a text file and add to a list

Tags: c#, list, file-io

I am having a text file like this. I'd like to read line by line and store these information into a `List<Store>`, with `Store` is a custom types.

```
Store ID: 01
Name: Kingfisher
Branch Number: 1
Address: 23 Emerson St
Phone: 422361609
-----END OF RECORD-----

Store ID: 02
Name: Harvey
Branch Number: 2
Address: 23 Korby St
Phone: 422361609
-----END OF RECORD-----

Store ID: 175
Name: Roger
Branch Number: 4
Address: 275 Carmody Rd
Phone: 428395719
-----END OF RECORD-----
```

Here is what I am using. Because the record is always with the order shown in the list, so I read line by line and assign the `store.ID`, `store.name`,... until it reaches the final attribute of a record is `store.phoneNumber`, it will then add it to the List and keep going in the `foreach` loop when it comes to the next `Store ID`.

But the problem is when I do search in the list, it can only return the final record. It seems like the List only has one element, which is the final record. Can anyone please point out where I am wrong?

```
    var storeTemp = new Store();
    List<Store> stores = new List<Store>();
    foreach (string line in File.ReadAllLines(@"C:\Store.txt"))
    {
        if (line.Contains("Store ID: "))
            storeTemp.ID = line.Substring(10);
        if (line.Contains("Name: "))
            storeTemp.name = line.Substring(6);
        if (line.Contains("Branch Number: "))
            storeTemp.branchNO = Convert.ToInt32(line.Substring(15));
        if (line.Contains("Address: "))
            storeTemp.address = line.Substring(9);
        if (line.Contains("Phone: "))
        {
            storeTemp.phoneNumber = Convert.ToInt32(line.Substring(7));
            stores.Add(storeTemp);
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
        List<Store> stores = new List<Store>();
            var storeTemp = new Store();

        foreach (string line in File.ReadAllLines(@"C:\Store.txt"))
        {
            // You needto create a new instance each time
            if (line.Contains("Store ID: "))
                storeTemp.ID = line.Substring(10);
            if (line.Contains("Name: "))
                storeTemp.name = line.Substring(6);
            if (line.Contains("Branch Number: "))
                storeTemp.branchNO = Convert.ToInt32(line.Substring(15));
            if (line.Contains("Address: "))
                storeTemp.address = line.Substring(9);
            if (line.Contains("Phone: "))
            {
                storeTemp.phoneNumber = Convert.ToInt32(line.Substring(7));
                stores.Add(storeTemp);
                storeTemp = new Store(); // You need to recreate the object, otherwise you overwrite same instance

            }
        }
```

Comment: awesome! thank you very much. I thought once we add the `storeTemp` to the `List<Stores>`, we can overwrite it

Answer (score 4):

I would use `LINQ` instead and the [`Batch`](http://morelinq.googlecode.com/hg/docs/api/html/M_MoreLinq_MoreEnumerable_Batch__1.htm) method to create batches of lines so you  can set the properties easily:

```
File.ReadLines("path")
.Batch(5)
.Select(x => x.ToList())
.Select(values => new Store 
                  {
                     ID = values[0].Split(':').Trim(),
                     name = values[1].Split(':').Trim(),
                     branchNo = int.Parse(values[2].Split(':').Trim()),
                     address = values[3].Split(':').Trim(),
                     phoneNumber =int.Parse(values[4].Split(':').Trim())
                  }.ToList();
```

You need add reference to [MoreLINQ](https://www.nuget.org/packages/morelinq/) library in order to use `Batch` method.

Answer (score 0):

You much create a new space in memory for storeTemp everytime . Currently you are over writing the data in the same location .

Comment: create a new instance of Store in the for loop is correct. But it should be recreated after adding to the List, like Max's answer above. If we put the code like you, it will create storeTemp for each line when it reads the file

Answer (score 0):

Just change the type of Store from `Class` to `Struct`